C++ template function within template class
I am writing a template matrix class supporting different data types, part of the class definition is
template <typename T>
    class Matrix
    {
    private:
        size_t rows;
        size_t cols;
        std::shared_ptr<T[]> data;

I need to implement an operator overloading function which supporting matrix-matrix addition as wells as matrix-constant addition:
template <typename T>
    Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator+(const Matrix<T> &other) const{
size_t length = this->cols * this->rows;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        {
            result.data[i] = this->data[i] + other.data[i];
        }
}

template <typename T>
template <typename U>
    Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::Matrix::operator+(U num){
size_t length = this->cols * this->rows;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        {
            result.data[i] = this->data[i] + num;
        }
}

However, when I am doing matrix-matrix addtion, the compiler seems to fail differentiate between these two functions and error is like this:
WellsMatrixLib::Matrix<double> a(5,5);
    WellsMatrixLib::Matrix<double> b(5,5);
    a.fill(5);
    b.fill(6);
    std::cout << a(1,1) << std::endl;
    WellsMatrixLib::Matrix<double> c = a + b;

In file included from main.cpp:1:
matrix.cpp: In instantiation of ‘WellsMatrixLib::Matrix<T> WellsMatrixLib::Matrix<T>::operator+(U) [with U = WellsMatrixLib::Matrix<double>; T = double]’:
main.cpp:8:44:   required from here
matrix.cpp:168:28: error: cannot convert ‘WellsMatrixLib::Matrix<double>’ to ‘std::__shared_ptr_access<double [], __gnu_cxx::_S_atomic, true, false>::element_type’ {aka ‘double’} in assignment
  168 |             result.data[i] = this->data[i] + num;
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Is there any way I can avoid this except that changing U to T.

We need a [mcve]. Something that can be copy/pasted into a compiler and reproduce the issue/error etc.

A side note: why do you use std::shared_ptr<T[]> data; ? Why not simply hold the data in a std::vector<T> ?

If shared_ptr is not relevant to the issue/error then you can remove it from the [mcve]

@wohlstad Since I need to implement ROI(Region of Interest) and memory hard copy is not allowed when a matrix is assigned to another. std::shared_ptr<T[]> seems like a good option for me to avoid double release?

I also advice you to use std::vector<T> instead of std::shared_ptr<T[]> data; your matrix should be the one and only owner of the data.  (Selecting a shared_ptr should come with a very good design rationale, if it just seems convenenient it is probably not the right choice)

To avoid double release, implement move constructors.

@Wells you mean that you need the data to be reference counted, similar to the way opencv cv::Mat behaves ?

@wohlstad yes, I am taking cv::Mat as an example.

@Wells In this case I recommend you to have a look at the opencv sources (since it is open source) to get some inspiration. Anyway writing a good generic Matrix container (with ROI support etc.) is far from being trivial. Unless you do it for educational reasons you might consider to use an existing implementation.

@JaMiT The error comes from the fact that compiler chose operator+(U) instead of operator+(const Matrix<T> &), we don't really have to see either implementation.

@Wells TBH, I'm not sure why compiler chooses operator+(U), the other one seems matching and more constrained. Without digging for full answer, a solution would be to constrain the U template to only accept numeric types. In C++20: template <typename T> concept ArithmeticType = std::is_arithmetic_v<T>; template <typename T> template <ArithmeticType U> Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::Matrix::operator+(U num) //...

As written, U can be any type, including Matrix<T>. I'm not sure why not simply declare that as Matrix operator+(T num) const but if you want to constrain U to potential elements of Matrix, look up std::enable_if... or C++20 constraints.

@Yksisarvinen "we don't really have to see either implementation" -- It does help if someone wants to play around with the code and see if the missing const is relevant. But as it is, the code still needs too much work to get to the stated error for my tastes (no constructor taking two numbers, no declarations for the operators in the class definition, missing headers, etc.).

the first operator+ is const-qualified, while the second is not.
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix<T> operator+(const Matrix<T> &other) const
    {
        std::cout <<"matrix + matrix" << std::endl;
        return {};
    }

    template <typename U>
    Matrix<T> operator+(U num)
    {
        std::cout <<"matrix + scalar" << std::endl;
        return {};      
    }
};

int main()
{
    Matrix<double> a,b;
    a+b;
}

Output:
matrix + scalar

The second variant is preferable, because the declaration of the first operand a is not const qualified.
Here, there is similar example
class Matrix {};

void f(const Matrix&, const Matrix&)
{
    std::cout <<"First" << std::endl;
}

template <typename U>
void f(Matrix&, U)
{
    std::cout <<"Second" << std::endl;
}


int main() {
    Matrix a,b;
    f(a, b);    // call f(Matrix&, U)
                // 1st argument: non-const a -> Matrix& is better than non-const a -> const Matrix&
                // 2nd argument: non-const b -> template parameter U is better than non-const b -> const Matrix&
}


Thanks :)) I understand this thoroughly
